# How to ignore row of null column values in SQL Server query when another row exists with non null column values for the same Id

Tags: sql, sql-server

Note: Honestly, not sure how to title this. :/

Using the following SQL query I get the following results.

```
select distinct P.ID
        ,P.LASTNAME
        ,P.FIRSTNAME
        ,T.FLAG
        ,CASE WHEN T.FLAG = 'T' THEN T.NAME ELSE NULL END AS NAME
        ,CASE WHEN T.FLAG = 'T' THEN R.T_NUMBER ELSE NULL END AS T_NUMBER
        ,CASE WHEN T.FLAG = 'T' THEN T.E_NUMBER ELSE NULL END AS E_NUMBER
        ,CASE WHEN T.FLAG = 'T' THEN R.S_NUMBER ELSE NULL END AS S_NUMBER
from P
left outer join R on R.P_ID = P.ID 
left outer join T on T.ID = R.T_ID




ID  LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   FLAG    NAME    T_NUMBER    E_NUMBER    S_NUMBER
11  ME          LOU         F       NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
11  ME          LOU         T       NAME1   11          123         11115
11  ME          LOU         T       NAME2   22          456         22225
11  ME          LOU         T       NAME3   33          789         33335
11  ME          LOU         T       NAME4   44          012         44445
12  DON         JOE         NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
13  SAM         CAR         NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
```

What changes do I make to the query so that the first row isn't returned in the result set because of the other ID 11 rows with data while still returning rows like the last two because there are no other rows for IDs 12 and 13?

Given an ID, if there exists a row with the same ID containing non null NAME, T_NUMBER, E_NUMBER, S_NUMBER data, then I do not also want a row that contains null in all these columns.
Below is the desired output I would like.

```
ID  LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   FLAG    NAME    T_NUMBER    E_NUMBER    S_NUMBER
11  ME          LOU         T       NAME1   11          123         11115
11  ME          LOU         T       NAME2   22          456         22225
11  ME          LOU         T       NAME3   33          789         33335
11  ME          LOU         T       NAME4   44          012         44445
12  DON         JOE         NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
13  SAM         CAR         NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
```

I've tried/tested using `distinct`, `group by`, `union` without success.

The reason I don't want the first row for `ME LOU` is because I know there exists records with more data and I can get the person's name from those records.

The reason I want the last two rows is because I still want that person record so that I know they exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter out `'F'` rows where there are is than 1 row.  If so:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1 or flag <> 'F';
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex your real query is, you can also do it in two `UNION` statements, both excluding the condition you don't want:

```
select distinct P.ID
        ,P.LASTNAME
        ,P.FIRSTNAME
        ,T.FLAG
        ,T.NAME AS NAME
        ,R.T_NUMBER AS T_NUMBER
        ,T.E_NUMBER AS E_NUMBER
        ,R.S_NUMBER AS S_NUMBER
from P
inner join R on R.P_ID = P.ID 
inner join T on T.ID = R.T_ID
where
T.FLAG = 'T'  -- excludes T.FLAG = 'F'

UNION ALL

select P.ID
        ,P.LASTNAME
        ,P.FIRSTNAME
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
from P
left outer join R on P.ID = R.P_ID  
where
R.T_ID is null  -- excludes T.FLAG is not null
```